# Best way to handle sequence of clicks in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

Let assume I have a canvas filled with rectangles, databound to a viewmodel.

Now I want to "select" a rectangle, so I've added a Select command to the rectangle class, and bound that to the rectangles.
This works fine.

The problem is this selection will have consequences. Easiest example is that selecting one rectangle should deselect any previous.

One way to deal with this would be to change the command (using relaycommands here) from

```
_ => this.Selected = true
```

to

```
_ => ParentVM.SetSelected(this)
```

This feels a bit nasty. "Loosening" the 2-way dependency by some DI framework just feels contrived in this example.

I'm guessing another way would be to solve this at the "WPF level", by using the bubbling of events, but I'm not sure that it's a better solution?

Anyone have any good suggestion?

EDIT: Got a good tip in the comments below about inheriting "Selector". This is an excellent suggestion, but unfortunately I left out a detail above, that i didn't think mattered.

The real problem is that I want to first select one of the rectangles, and then another one and get, say, the distance between them displayed. So one of them is the "first selected" and the other is the "second selected".

Comment: You should use something that inherits from `Selector` like the `ListBox` and let the control handle the selection.

Comment: I agree with @NovitchiS If you have your own shape and inherit the Selector, Collection views ect will handle all the un-selecting and selecting events for you. You get alot for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am not understanding the requirement, this is what I would do.

1. Create a property (on the VM if using MVVM) which will hold a reference to the last rectangle which has been selected.
2. Require each rectangle to report itself when its selected, by either, owning a bound reference to that aforementioned property or by using a `commanding` operation where it reports itself as the reference.
3. Inside the setter of the property created, take the old one (if it exists) and the new one, determine the distance and put that on another property on the VM and then hold the reference to the currently selected one.

Comment: Ok, that idea is basically a (much better) variation on my initial suggestion. I made a similar solution (have the main VM implement an interface ICanSetSelected).